# compute eigendecomposition to find eigenvalues and eigenvector

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd, principal-component-analysis

So I have matrix A which has (*m×d*) dimension and X = A.A^T

My X has *d* non-zero distinct eigenvalues and *m > d*

Usually I compute eigendecomposition matrix which has (*mxm*) dimension to find eigendecomposition of X and from there I can find eigenvalues and eigenvector of X. But my m is larger than d, so it is slower.

Assume I have an eigendecomposition “black box” subroutine (I'm not using SVD as a black box), how can I find eigenvalue and eigenvector of X using eigendecomposition matrix which has (*d×d*) dimension?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y$ is an eigenvector of $A^{\intercal}A$ so that $A^{\intercal}Ay=\lambda y$.
Let $x=Ay$. Then,
$$
AA^{\intercal}x=A(\lambda y)=\lambda Ay=\lambda x
$$
and hence $x$ is an eigenvector $AA^{\intercal}$.
In particular, this implies that $A^{\intercal}A$ and $AA^{\intercal}$ share $d$ (possibly nonzero) eigenvalues. The remaining eigenvalues of $AA^{\intercal}$
are guaranteed to be zero.

This means that we can compute the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{d}$ and eigenvectors $y_{1},\ldots,y_{d}$ of $A^{\intercal}A$ and obtain the corresponding pairs for $AA^{\intercal}$ by computing $x_{i}=Ay_{i}$ for each $i=1,\ldots,d$.